# Read HTTP header ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, http-headers

I have a project that uses an Apache server that demands NTLM auth. If i look with packetracer to the http packets i can see the username in clear text.

My question is how do i read the http headers of the current connection.
I have tried:

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.knowbase.be')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('http://www.knowbase.be')
@res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

But that gives a http request from server side. Can someone help me with this!
I need this functionality for implementing this --> [Tutorial](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/12/02/ntlm-windows-domain-authentication-for-rails-application/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably look at the contents of `request.headers`, see [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers). Some tweaking in Apache may be necessary to get the correct header forwarded to Rails.

Comment: You are my hero! Was looking for this a long time

Comment: Well in my own time, I had been looking for this long time as well... Until I though "well it'd make sense for it to be in something like `request.headers`"... I tried it, and I was like "oh right..." :)